# javascriptでスロットマシン

Tags: javascript

自分は今、Javascriptでスロットマシンを作っています。
そこで質問なんですが、スタートボタンを連打しますとリールの回転が速くなってしまいます。
回転速度は一定のままにしたいです。
そしてアタリ、ハズレの判定が消えません。
どうしたらよろしいでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Javascript

```
//左リールの制御
function a1() {

    //aにHTMLから取得した数字を代入
    var a=document.getElementById("su1").innerHTML;

    //文字列のiを数字に変換し１を足してxに代入
    var x=parseInt(a)+1;

    //取得した値が９を超えたら１に戻す
    if(x>9) {
    x=1;
    }
    //xに書き換えてして表示する
    document.getElementById("su1").innerHTML=x;

    //一定期間繰り返す
    TimeoutID1=setTimeout("a1()",100);
    }





    //スタートボタンを押すと６を表示する
    function rstart() {
     a2();
     a1();
     a3();
    }

//真ん中のリールの制御
function a2() {

    //iにHTMLから取得した数字を代入
    var i=document.getElementById("su2").innerHTML;

    //文字列のiを数字に変換し１を足してjに代入
    var j=parseInt(i)+1;

    //取得した値が９を超えたら１に戻す
    if(j>9) {
     j=1;
    }

    //Jに書き換えてして表示する
    document.getElementById("su2").innerHTML=j;

    //一定期間繰り返す
    TimeoutID2=setTimeout("a2()",100);
    }



//右のリールの制御
function a3() {
    var c=document.getElementById("su3").innerHTML;

    //文字列のiを数字に変換し１を足してjに代入

    var z=parseInt(c)+1;
     if(z>9) {
     z=1;
    }

    //zに書き換えてして表示する
    document.getElementById("su3").innerHTML=z;

    //一定期間繰り返す
    TimeoutID3=setTimeout("a3()",100);

    }

//三つのリールを止める
 function stop(btn) {
    if(btn == 0) {clearTimeout(TimeoutID1);TimeoutID1=0;}
    if(btn == 1) {clearTimeout(TimeoutID2);TimeoutID2=0;}
    if(btn == 2) {clearTimeout(TimeoutID3);TimeoutID3=0;}

    //su1,su2,su3の値が同じなら"skekka"にあたりを表示、それ以外ならはずれを表示
    if(!(TimeoutID1 | TimeoutID2 | TimeoutID3)){
    if(document.getElementById("su1").innerHTML == document.getElementById("su2").innerHTML
    && document.getElementById("su2").innerHTML == document.getElementById("su3").innerHTML){
    document.getElementById("skekka").innerHTML="あたり";
    }else{
    document.getElementById("skekka").innerHTML="はずれ";
    }
    }
    }
```

HTML

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=Shift_JIS">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css">
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="sample1.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
   <form name="game">
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    .surot{text-align:center;font-size:38;font-weight:bold;color:#ff0000;width:90;height:65;background-color:#0000ff;}
    .surot2{font-size:14pt;font-weight:bold;color:#0000ff;text-align:center;width:96;}
-->
    -->
    </style>
    <p style="text-align:center;font-size:24pt;font-weight:bold;">スロットマシン</p>
    <table border="0" style="margin-left:150;margin-bottom:0;">
      <tr>
        <td id="skekka" style="font-size:34;font-weight:bold;color:#ff0000;width:200;height:40;text-align:center;"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="background-color:#00ff00;border:solid #00ff00 5;margin-left:100;margin-bottom:0;">
      <tr>
        <td id="su1" class="surot">0<td>
        <td id="su2" class="surot">0<td>
        <td id="su3" class="surot">0<td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="margin-left:100;">
      <tr>
        <td><input type="button" value="ストップ" onClick="stop(0)" class="surot2"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="ストップ" onClick="stop(1)" class="surot2"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value="ストップ" onClick="stop(2)" class="surot2"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <div style="position:absolute;top:125;left:450;" >
      <input type="button" value="スタート" onClick="rstart()" style="font-size:16pt;font-weight:bold;color:#0000ff;">
    </div>
   </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: 人に丸ごとデバッグをさせるような質問は避けるべきです。

Answer (score 1):

回答としては[前回の質問](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/12842/)に対するものとほぼ同じです。前回でも説明したように、**コードをどう変更すればいいのかわからないのは、そのコードが未整理で煩雑すぎるのが原因のひとつ**です。質問のような機能追加や変更は本来的には難しくありません。でも、**たとえ簡単な機能の追加でも、それを未整理で入り組んだコードに施すのはとても難しい作業になりますし、もし出来たとしてもその変更は更にコードを複雑にするので、このままではコードの複雑さは際限なく増大してやがて開発が破綻するのが目に見えています**。前回言った通りの方針で一旦コードを整理してからでないと、これ以上の機能追加や変更は難しいでしょう。

前回の回答がほとんど生かされていないようですが、回答が生かされないのであれば同じような質問を何度したところで進歩は望めないでしょう。前回も言いましたが、機能の追加や不具合の修正を考える前に、とにかくまずはコードを十分に整理してください。

Answer (score 1):

> 回転速度は一定のままにしたいです。

2度押しを禁止するロジックを追加する必要があります。
つまり、「スタート」から「全てストップ」の状態の間、「rstart() は何もしない」という処理を入れるといいと思います。

> そしてアタリ、ハズレの判定が消えません。

こちらは、"skekka" に空文字を入れると消えますよ。